# MySQL Updating column based on other values

Tags: php, mysqli

I am building a simple gaming system and I was wondering how to get the users rank without calculating everytime the result in a query(maybe I should run a cron job?).
This is my `points` table structure at the moment:

```
+--username--+--rank--+--total_points--+
|######################################|
|    Mark    |   0    |      700       |
|------------+--------+----------------|
|    Luke    |   0    |      400       |
+------------+--------+----------------+
```

How do I update the `rank` column based on `total_points`?
Is there a better way to do this? Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only one query:

```
UPDATE
    users,
    (SELECT
        @row:=@row+1 rownum,
        username
    FROM users,
        (SELECT @row := 0) r
    ORDER BY total_points DESC) as rank_ord
SET users.rank = rank_ord.row
WHERE users.username = rank.username;
```

If your table contains an index column (other then username), then change the condition

```
WHERE users.username = rank.username
```

to

```
WHERE users.id = rank.id
```

to make it faster.

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the rank depends on `total_points` you just need to sort query results by `total_points DESC` and row number is your position in rank. No need to calculate anything. Of course you may have two users with same `total_points` so if you want to have same rank this will not work, but you can do pretty simple the same approach (**pseudo code**):

```
$rows = query with order total_points DESC
$rank = 0;
$last_total_points = -1;
foreach( $rows as $row ) {
   if( $row['total_points'] != $last_total_points ) {
      $rank++;
      $last_total_points = $row['total_points'];
   }

   update that row with $rank;
}
```

so at the end, you will get all users ranked with the same rank for equal total_points values too